Issues with program in LC3 (4 digit addition, problems with TRAP instructions)
This is my assignment prompt:
Objective
Create a LC-3 program that will perform addition (optionally more operations) on
numbers with 4 digits or less.
Problem Statement
We are now familiar with the LC-3 simulator and can debug and develop asm code.
For this assignment, you are to develop a LC-3 assembly program to perform math
operations and display the result on the screen.
A skeleton code is NOT provided to you. You are to develop your own program to
accomplish this task. Feel free to refer to previous labs for ideas.
The requirement for the lab is to ask the user to enter two numbers of up to four digits
in length and display their sum. The expected program output is shown below.
Please enter SRC1:
1234
Please enter SRC2:
4321
The sum is:
5555
I have tried coding myself and finding help online to no avail. I believe something may be wrong with the simulator or something because my main issue atm is that whenever an instruction that calls to the keyboard or display box (such as PUTS or OUT or any TRAP command) the program hits an IllegalInstructionException saying "Undefined Instruction x0000". It sends the whole program to address x0000 and stops working. It's likely I'm just being dumb and making some silly mistake but I wanted to bring it here for guidance because I am lost.
Here is the code I have so far:
Again the main issue is the crashing during certain commands but I am also generally pretty lost on how to write this so any other feedback is appreciated.
.ORIG x3000

        LEA     R0, PROMPT1    ; Load address of first prompt message
        TRAP    x22            ; Print first prompt
        JSR     GET_NUMBER     ; Read first number
        LD      R1, NUM1       ; Load first number

        LEA     R0, PROMPT2    ; Load address of second prompt message
        TRAP    x22            ; Print second prompt
        JSR     GET_NUMBER     ; Read second number
        LD      R2, NUM1       ; Load second number

        ADD     R3, R1, R2     ; Add the two numbers

        JSR     CONVERT_SUM    ; Convert sum to ASCII
        JSR     DISPLAY_RESULT ; Display the sum

        HALT

GET_NUMBER
        AND     R1, R1, #0     ; Clear R1 to store the number
        ADD     R2, R2, #0     ; Clear R2 for character conversion
       
    LOOP   TRAP    x23            ; Read a character
        ADD     R0, R0, #-10   ; Convert character to integer
        BRzp    LOOP           ; If positive, continue reading
        ADD     R1, R1, R2     ; Add the digit to the number
        ADD     R1, R1, R0     ; Add the next digit
        ADD     R1, R1, R1     ; Multiply by 2 (shift left)
        ADD     R1, R1, R1     ; Multiply by 4 (shift left again)
        ADD     R1, R1, R0     ; Add the final digit
        RET

CONVERT_SUM
        LD      R4, NEG30      ; Load the value of -30 into R4
        ADD     R3, R3, R4     ; Subtract 30 from R3 using R4 to adjust the sum to ASCII
        RET

DISPLAY_RESULT
        LEA     R0, RESULT     ; Load address of result message
        TRAP    x22            ; Print result message
        ADD     R0, R3, #0     ; Load the sum from R3
        TRAP    x21            ; Print the sum
        RET

NUM1    .BLKW   1             ; Variable to store first number
NUM2    .BLKW   1             ; Variable to store second number
RESULT  .STRINGZ "The sum is: "
PROMPT1 .STRINGZ "Please enter SRC1: "
PROMPT2 .STRINGZ "Please enter SRC2: "
NEG30   .FILL   #-30  
.END


So, are you saying it does not even print the PROMPT1? This does not seem to meet the "minimal" requirement of a [mcve] then. PS: [edit] your  question and fix the formatting using the code button on the toolbar.

Try to get a very small simple program working, 10 lines or less.  Test each capability you need in that manner before attempting to write a hundred line program.

I dont know how to reply to comments but I tried running just this simple program
.ORIG x3000
LEA     R0, PROMPT1 ;
TRAP    x22     ;
PROMPT1 .STRINGZ "TEST TEST!"
.END
and even this does not run... is there something wrong with this code or is it my simulator?

See, that is a [mcve]. That should work, if it does not then indeed something wrong with your sim. Where did you get it from? PS: since that has no ending, it will crash but only after printing the message.
